# How to rewrite this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, continuity

This is probably an easy Analysis exercise:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary (like a sphere) and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Assume now that for all $x_0 \in \partial A$ we have $$\lim_{A \ni x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) =0.$$ That means, $f$ is continuous on the boundary of $A$ and constant $0$.

Let $x_r \in A$ be arbitrary with $dist(x_r, \partial A)<r$, that means the (euclidean) distance between $x_r$ and the boundary of $A$ is less than $r$.

How can I now conclude formally correct that

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} f(x_r) =0.$$

It would be trivial if $x_r$ converged to a point but this is not true in general. So I don't have a point $x_0 \in \partial A$ which I can use to exploit the continuity at $x_0$.

What can I do else?

Comment: What is an easy bounded domain?

Comment: @humanStampedist I made it clearer ;)

Comment: If the first convergence is uniform (i.e. $\delta/\epsilon$ independent of $x_0$), then yes. Note that your limit with $r\to0$ involves the values of $f$ on an offset surface of $\partial A$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That would be equivalent to $f$ being uniformly continuous, right? This is true since $f$ is continuous and the closure of $A$ is compact.